# These tags should probably be blacklisted.

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist

I just removed all the few questions tagged [it](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/it), and I was thinking about removing [system-administration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/system-administration) for the ~27 questions, but I didn't really want to bump all those questions.  I think both of these tags should be blacklisted here, since almost every question should be able about system administration.

Comment: @sysadmin1138, Is inserting tags something we can all do but I never noticed or is it a mod and up thing only?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Special syntax `[tag:microsoft]` will do it now.

Comment: Could we get rid of the 'vmware' tag too please, there isn't any software called VMWare but that company does make lots of different products and it frustrates me as I answer a lot of them, it might force the questioner to add this vital information from the start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, I blacklisted `^(system-administration|it)$` from tags, and destroyed [system-administration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/system-administration) -- these are what we call "intrinsic" tags meaning they are assumed on the site, like you wouldn't tag a question on apple.se [apple] because, well, they're *all* apple questions.

These intrinsic tags are also checked on migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, tag blacklisting is not one of the superpowers I have at my finger-tips. There might be a dev-tool for that.

On the other hand, I can destroy [system-administration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/system-administration) with fire.

Comment: Also, a bunch of the system-administration tagged questions could be tagged `learning` as a more appropriate tag.

Comment: only devs can destroy tags, but diamonds can rename and merge tags. I would also argue learning is not a good tag either, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/