# Kill [sysadmin] tag on SF with fire

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, blacklist

I humbly request that the [sysadmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin) tag on Serverfault be killed with fire.

Currently 384 questions tagged with it.  I expect quite a few of them may have been migrated to SF.

**EDIT:**
Any other thoughts on this?  I've retagged anything with just the single [sysadmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin) tag so killing this tag shouldn't leave anything orphaned (sorry for the homepage spam...)

Comment: To the mods, I remember somewhere @Jeff Atwood wanted a dev to delete tags to prevent back end stuff. Just a heads up.

Comment: Yup, this is a request for the devs.  Mods alone can't do it anymore.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks!

Comment: I thought this was a dup of this http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1298/these-tags-should-probably-be-blacklisted. I guess I didn't notice that sysadmin also existed when I made that request.  We should probably go check to see if there are any other [sysadmin] synonyms tags that also need to be killed.

Comment: Anything [sysadmin-*]

Comment: While we're at it, can anyone think of any others that should be eliminated? e.g. Should `server` be on that list or not?

Comment: +1 for "Kill-with-fire" tag!

Comment: @Chris heh, let's just hope I don't end up with a taxonomist for that one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 6):

Doubleplusgood idea.

As for other tags, I'd personally also burn as worthless: server, computer - or any others so hopelessly vague as to defeat the purpose of tagging entirely. These strike me as analogous to tagging SO questions with 'code' or 'programming'.  (Accurate but useless)

Unless someone can think of a way the 'server' tag's 2k+ results would help narrow down a search? (Not sarcastic)

Comment: are server and computer still around? Eeeek, computer was.. burninated. If you see any more let me know.