# Prevent editing a closed question from it being bumped to front page.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

Visting ServerFault this morning there were a large number of old questions (posted 2009) that have been edited and therefore bumped to the front page. While I find this highly irritaing as it is, two of these questions were already closed ([one](https://serverfault.com/questions/207787/engineer-tech-support) | [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/17269/how-to-deal-with-a-stubborn-sysadmin)) so apart from having the questions bumped to the front page and a tag added they have very little use.

I would go so far to ask that tag-only edits don't bump the question.

Comment: Totally agree about not bumping closed questions, not sure about not bumping after tag change - after all it will cause the correct people to see it won't it?

Comment: @Shadow, the majority of these questions have answers already so maybe in this case you are right. How about "Don't bump after tag change *if accepted*"?

Comment: If there is no bump after a tag change, it is less lickly that a invalid tab change will get stored out.

Comment: sounds good, however looks like it won't go through. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take that up with squillman (and this should not be asked here, so I am migrating it back to meta.sf)

https://serverfault.com/users/1054/squillman?tab=activity

Our policy has been stated many times on this -- edits bump the post to the homepage so that the community can vet the changes, *exactly like what is happening now*.

Comment: Sorry for the spamming, Jeff...  See my comment on @sysadmin 's answer.

Answer (score 4):

As Jeff said, this is done on purpose and isn't going to change. Edits need vetting, tag-edits perhaps more so since the rep requirements to do them are a lot lower. We haven't had much edit-abuse here on SF, thankfully, but we do need to keep bumping anything that gets edited.

Where it gets annoying is when someone is doing a manual retag of a bunch of questions. A month or two ago we were doing much the same with the [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) tag (well, mostly Iain did), which required going through hundreds of questions. It also took a long time since the **etiquette** most of us follow is to do a few at a time to avoid spamming the heck out of the main page and push legitimate new questions w-a-y down where they won't get attention.

Comment: How about a checkbox visible for members with, say, 2k+ rep that says "Don't bump to front page". This would prevent flooding the page with edited questions in the scenario you just described?

Comment: @tom I think it was also fairly mild in this case, you're talking about, what.. 6-8 posts? I don't support a "make my edit secret so nobody can double-check it" checkbox, by the way.

Comment: @Jeff your point is fair, for 8 posts. For @SysAdmin1138's mass retag a button would be useful, although (due to the "hide it and hope no-one notices" abuse potential) I did suggest a minimum rep (or even mod status).

Comment: Yes, that's on me and I am sorry for the homepage spam. Sorry guys, I'll keep it to a minimum if I do that again.  In this case I was retagging questions that had the single [tag:sysadmin] tag hoping that we could kill that tag (from a previous request I posted).

Comment: @squill do you want the [sysadmin] tag destroyed? I can do that

Comment: @Jeff Yes, see my question from a while back - http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1341/kill-sysadmin-tag-on-sf-with-fire

Comment: @squillman, sorry, I should have contacted you through other means than M.SO/M.SF. Thanks, though.