# Please burninate the [local] tag

Tags: support, tags

[local](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/local) needs to die.

There are currently 55 questions with this tag.  All of them have at least 1 other tag.  Can't see any possible reason to keep it.

Comment: A very quick look at that list makes me wonder about some of the other tags used, such as `line` and `com`. Maybe someone with more time to spare than I have could look at those.

Comment: If we are agreed, with only 55 questions this could be done over a weekend.

Comment: Someone else can do it.  I got lambasted for spamming the home page last time I did that.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1657/prevent-editing-a-closed-question-from-it-being-bumped-to-front-page

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: *sigh* "Someone" burninated the [tag:kill-with-fire] tag that I created last time I made a request...

Comment: We'll just have to use the image.